# Fully synced bitcoind 0.18.1 on RPI4 using 100% cpu ( 1 core only ) , is it normal?

Tags: bitcoind, raspberry-pi

I started playing with bitcoind 0.18.1 on a RPI4 and i can see that even when fully synced it is still using 100% cpu so one full core.

Is this normal / expected ?

Looking at the threads is the `bitcoin-msghand` (ler?) thread that is doing the work

```
 5946 999       20   0  557016 410080   3392 R  98.8  10.2 226:58.92 bitcoin-msghand
```

could it be that my `dbcache=100` is causing it to do much IO while relaying data to other peers ? 
To be fair i don't see much IO at all

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same behavior with a x86 cpu (j5005).

`b-msghand` is a network thread that handles "application level message (sending and receiving). Almost all net_processing and validation logic runs on this thread."

So my solution has been to reduce `-maxconnections` to 60 (from the default 125) and I have never seen it again using 100% of 1 core.